# Plotting shapely polygon with holes does not plot all holes

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a filled `shapely.geometry.Polygon` polygon with holes in. I have tried 2 methods, both give the same result. Below is the code I have been using to debug

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Polygon exterior:
p = [[20,767],[54,744],[107,707],
 [190,654],[265,609],[363,548],
 [462,484],[514,447],[603,389],
 [682,337],[726,310],[757,290],
 [786,277],[820,259],[843,249],
 [881,231],[921,215],[975,197],
 [1048,174],[1089,163],[1141,152],
 [1212,137],[1270,121],[1271,64],
 [1207,78],[1163,89],[1096,103],
 [1048,115],[1001,129],[949,144],
 [905,157],[874,170],[830,187],
 [781,208],[730,236],[696,255],
 [652,282],[606,306],[561,340],
 [512,370],[478,393],[436,418],
 [385,453],[330,490],[285,521],
 [229,566],[183,603],[123,652],
 [70,698],[13,749]]

# Define interior "holes":
interiors = {}
interiors[0] = [[290,543],[301,560],[393,501],[377,482]]
interiors[1] = [[507,392],[549,363],[553,367],[572,352],[588,372],[522,415]]
interiors[2] = [[599,340],[636,316],[648,334],[612,357]]
interiors[3] = [[714,262],[727,284],[821,238],[811,215]]
interiors[4] = [[850,218],[935,185],[937,187],[850,221]]
interiors[5] = [[959,159],[1066,129],[1071,146],[966,177]]
interiors[6] = [[1119,133],[1175,122],[1178,123],[1119,134]]
interiors[7] = [[1211,102],[1266,91],[1267,97],[1212,108],[1211,102]]

i_p = {k: Polygon(v) for k, v in interiors.items()}


zone = Polygon(p, [zone.exterior.coords for zone in i_p.values() \
                    if zone.within(Polygon(p)) is True])
```

I now have a `Polygon` called `zone` which I think *should* have the correct exterior and interior. Working in a jupyter notebook I am able to run a cell with just the object name

```py
zone
```

[image]

As hoped for the polygon displays correctly. However I now want to plot this polygon in all sorts of other places, so I look online and try to use `descartes.PolygonPatch`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patch = PolygonPatch(zone)
ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1300)
ax.set_ylim(0, 777)
plt.show()
```

The output is now incorrect, two of the interior areas are filled in. Checking that a point that lies in one of these interior holes is not within the `zone` polygon with `zone.contains(<point>)` returns a `False` (as desired). However running the same method on the `PolygonPatch` created, `patch`, returned `True`. Each interior returned `True` to `is_closed()`.
[image]

I then tried `geopandas` and returned the same

```py
p = gpd.GeoSeries(zone)
p.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I have also spent hours trying to find what method is running to produce the first plot when the object `zone` is "run" in interactive python, as I figure that could give me some insight.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that exterior and interiors have a canonical form which assumes counter-clockwise coordinates for exterior and clockwise for interiors. You have to normalize your result to see it correctly. Shapely does not have `normalize` function yet (which is available in PyGEOS) but doing the `buffer(0)` does the trick.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patch = PolygonPatch(zone.buffer(0))
ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1300)
ax.set_ylim(0, 777)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered - the interior boundary must be clockwise if the exterior is counterclockwise (need to has opposite rotational direction). Of course it cannot cross itself. This is because matplotlib treats it like a single polygon that has very thin line connecting hole with outer space, but it is not plot as contour.

The simplest way is to invert the list of points for wrongly plotted interior curves:

```
for index, curve in interiors.items():
    if is_the_other_way_around(curve):
        interiors[index] = curve[::-1]
```

if you need to check it automatically you can use this method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order