# Unwanted filling of inner polygons when clipping a shapefile with another shapefile in Python

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, geopandas

I'm trying to clip a shapefile with another .shp using pure python.

Original shp I need to clip:

[image]

Area of Interest for clipping (shown overlapped to the original .shp for convenience):

[image]

If I invoke `clipvectorbypolygon` from QGIS toolbox via `processing.run`, I get the desired result:

```
params = {'INPUT': original_shape,
          'MASK': area_of_interest,
          'OPTIONS':'',
          'OUTPUT': result_shape
         }

processing.run("gdal:clipvectorbypolygon", parameters = params)
```

[image]

But, when trying to replicate it using pure python, I always obtain a clipped polygon with the inner areas filled:

I've tried by using `geopandas.clip`

```
input = gpd.read_file(original_shape)

clipped = gpd.clip(input, area_of_interest)

clipped.to_file(result_shape)
```

and `geopandas.GeoSeries.intersection`:

```
input = gpd.read_file(original_shape)

clipped = gpd.GeoSeries.intersection(input, area_of_interest)

clipped.to_file(result_shape)
```

Both produce the same result:

[image]

**exploding** the original .shp gives a slightly different output, but same problem:

```
input = gpd.read_file(original_shape).explode()

for index, row in input['geometry'].iteritems():
    clipped = gpd.clip(area_of_interest, row)
    clipped.to_file(os.path.join(output_path, f'{index}.shp'))
```

[image]

The only way of not getting filled polygons is passing as mask just the extent of the Area of Interest with `total_bounds`, but (predictably) the output is a shape with more geometry as needed:

```
input = gpd.read_file(original_shape)

clipped = gpd.clip(input, area_of_interest.total_bounds)

clipped.to_file(result_shape)
```

[image]

EDIT: Additional info

The problem seems to be when the result is written to a file. Plotting *clipped* apparently gives the expected outcome:

```
clipped.plot().axis('off')
clipped.boundary.plot().axis('off')
```

[image]

Comment: Look at [Plotting shapely polygon with holes does not plot all holes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/374006/2581)

Comment: Thanks @gene . It is still not working as intended even when applying buffer, but that gave me additional ideas to keep looking into the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In case of invalid geometry, you might get a result like this.

Try `make_valid` function of `shapely`

```
from shapely.validation import make_valid
```

Before clipping:

```
input_df["geometry"] = input_df.geometry.apply(make_valid)
```

or after clipping:

```
clipped["geometry"] = clipped.geometry.apply(make_valid)

clipped.to_file(result_shape)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. For better or worse, the geometry seems to be already valid and it doesn't have an impact on the outcome...

Comment: Could you share your data, if you don't mind?